# Aligning images under each other in several columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of images with different widths and heights, and I want to align them under each other (without vertical blank space in between) in say 4 columns. For example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/425063504039538688/sO0mRdKW.jpeg" width="300px">
        <img src="http://w-uh.com/images/1401/cool_picture.jpg" width="300px">
        <img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/l-These-are-pictures-of-Jari.jpg" width="300px">
        <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/21900000/Beautiful-Pictures-_-beautiful-pictures-21967793-1024-768.jpg" width="300px">
        <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22600000/Random-beautiful-pictures-22607571-500-333.jpg" width="300px">            
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/425946167050911744/x62a9eBz_400x400.jpeg" width="300px">
        <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/624_351/images/live/p0/16/0s/p0160sdl.jpg" width="300px">
        <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/01_01/Racecourse_650x311.jpg" width="300px">
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see there is blank space between pictures in first and second row. I want to align each image in such a way, so that there is no blank space between upper and lower images in a column. Live example: http://goldenrepublictattoo.com/collection

I have managed to align the last column with `float: left` property, but other columns stay unaligned. Is there something like `float: top` to align images under each other?

Comment: you are looking for `masonry` layout. see this link.. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with just CSS. Best bet is to use something like masonry. Or to write some custom JavaScript depending on how you want it to  behave.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <img class="item" />
  <img class="item" />
  <img class="item" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

**Demo and Doc:**

- http://masonry.desandro.com/
- http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/images.html

Comment: Good to know.. Maybe someday this will doable with CSS. But for now this is a popular option.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a Masonry layout library.  Google for `masonry layout`.

One I've used recently with good results:
http://yconst.com/web/freetile/

Answer (score 0):

MASONRY CSS

```css
*{
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ul{            
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 20px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
        position: relative;
        width: 980px;        
}
ul li{        
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;            
     margin-bottom: 20px;     
     width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/425063504039538688/sO0mRdKW.jpeg" width="300px">
         
      <li><img src="http://w-uh.com/images/1401/cool_picture.jpg" width="300px">
          
      <li><img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/l-These-are-pictures-of-Jari.jpg" width="300px">
          
        <li><img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/21900000/Beautiful-Pictures-_-beautiful-pictures-21967793-1024-768.jpg" width="300px">
            
        <li><img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22600000/Random-beautiful-pictures-22607571-500-333.jpg" width="300px"> 
            
         <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/425946167050911744/x62a9eBz_400x400.jpeg" width="300px">    
        
          <li><img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/624_351/images/live/p0/16/0s/p0160sdl.jpg" width="300px">
              
            <li><img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/01_01/Racecourse_650x311.jpg" width="300px">   
</ul>
```